# Replace a node with a duplicate using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I have a `div` element and I need to make a "backup" of it, to restore in certain occasions.

To clone the `div`, I'm using:

```
savedDiv = originalDiv.cloneNode(true);
```

And to restore it:

```
originalDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(savedDiv,originalDiv);
```

The problem is that I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null`

Any elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: `originalDiv.parentNode` is `null`

Comment: `originalDiv` was either detached from its parent by another piece of code or never actually attached.

Comment: I tried to print the parent before the `replaceChild` line and it's `[object HTMLDivElement]` so `originalDiv.parentNode` is not null and is attached

Comment: @AndiPavllo Could you plz create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was trying to execute this operation multiple times but it seems that, after the first time, originalDiv get's consumed.

I fixed it by initializing `originalDiv` again.